# How to call another action with parameter in rails active admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

First time using rails, everything seems alien, please be kind with this stupid question.

I code something like:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do

  member_action :action1 do
    <some code>
  end

  member_action :action2 do
    if(<some check>)
      <some work>
    else
      <here I need to call the action1 with parms action2 has>
    end
  end

end
```

How should I do this? How can I call action1 with the parms in the else block?

I tried

```
redirect_to action1(request.parameters)
```

It didn't work it throw error action1 is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

A `member_action` is a controller action and this will generate a route.
You should never call the one `member_action` from another.

**Approach1**:-  You can include the modules and add the method there.

i. `include` the module

```
include ActiveAdminHelper
ActiveAdmin.register Post do

  member_action :action1 do
    method1
  end

  member_action :action2 do
    if(<some check>)
      method1
    else
      method2
  end
end
```

ii. Add the file `app/helpers/active_admin_helper.rb`

```
module ActiveAdminHelper
  def method1
  end

  def method2
  end
end
```

**Approach2**:- Modifying the Controller
-> You can define the methods in the controller block

```
  ActiveAdmin.register Post do

    controller do
      # This code is evaluated within the controller class

      def define_a_method
        # Instance method
      end
    end
  end
```

For more details you can refer the doc [here](https://activeadmin.info/8-custom-actions.html)